# Restrict the maximum topic created by user

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there any way to configure Artemis broker so that user can have restriction on the maximum number of topics created under any address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking it is not possible to create a "topic" under an address in ActiveMQ Artemis. You can only create a queue under an address. The term "topic" is used to denote publish/subscribe semantics which is configured by defining an address which supports multicast routing.

It is possible to limit the number of queues a user can create using the `resource-limits`, e.g.:

```xml
<resource-limit-settings>
   <resource-limit-setting match="myUser">
      <max-queues>3</max-queues>
   </resource-limit-setting>
</resource-limit-settings>
```

You can read more about this in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/resource-limits.html).